# Is it possible to queue more than one context.load before context.sync?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I have a paragraphObjects of Word's paragraph objects. I have keywordRanges of indexes of some paragraphs and keywords. I have another array of keywords that I want to search and highlight in the document.

The issue is - the keyword search is linear. I have to `load` and `sync` the search result of each keyword. So if one keyword search takes ~300 ms, 15 search would take ~4500 seconds. I want to execute all keyword-search load-sync operations in parallel, so I get all the results in ~300 ms, independent of the size of the keywords array.

The code sample is below:

```
let paragraphObjects = []
let keywordsObject = {
  "2": {
    "keywords": ["the", "which", "eye"]
  },
  "4": {
    "keywords": ["lorem", "ipsum"]
  },
  "9": {
    "keywords": ["hellow", "world", "foo", "bar"]
  }
}
let keywordRanges = []
let searchKeywordResults = []

Word.run((context) => {

  var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs

  context.load(paragraphs, 'text, font, style');

  return context.sync().then(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
      paragraphObjects.push(paragraphs.items[i])
    }

    $.each(keywordsObject, (divId, divValue) => {
      $.each(divValue.keywords, (idx, keyword) => {
        var obj = { paragraphObject: pa[currentParaIndex], keyword: keyword }
        keywordRanges.push(obj)
      })
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    if (keywordRanges.length > 0) {
      $.each(keywordRanges, (idx, obj) => {
        var paragraphObject = obj.paragraphObject
        var keyword = obj.keyword
        searchKeywordResults[idx] = paragraphObject.search(keyword, { matchWholeWord: true })
      })

      let highlight = async() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < searchKeywordResults.length; i++) {
          context.load(searchKeywordResults[i], 'text, font')
          await context.sync() // each iteration takes around 300 milliseconds. 
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < searchKeywordResults.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < searchKeywordResults[i].items.length; j++) {
            searchKeywordResults[i].items[j].font.highlightColor = highlightColorValue
          }
        }

        await context.sync()
        return
      }

      highlight()
    }
  })
})
```

I want to replace this code with

```
for (let i = 0; i < searchKeywordResults.length; i++) {
    context.load(searchKeywordResults[i], 'text, font')
    await context.sync() 
}
```

with this

```
for (let i = 0; i < searchKeywordResults.length; i++) {
    context.load(searchKeywordResults[i], 'text, font')
}
await context.sync()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, queueing multiple operations in one `sync` is part and parcel of the batching model of the Office 2016+ wave of APIs.

To take a very simple Excel example:

```
async function run() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
            let a1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
            let b2 = sheet.getRange("B2");
            let c3 = sheet.getRange("C3");

            [a1, b2, c3].forEach(range => range.load("values"));

            await context.sync();

            [a1, b2, c3].forEach(range => console.log(range.values[0][0]));
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

So, it definitely should work.  Are you getting an error when you try something like this?

FWIW (disclaimer, I am the author of said book):  I think you will find a lot of useful info about loading and batching in the book "Building Office Add-in using Office.js", available at https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/.  Chapter 5 in particular -- about the fundamentals of Office.js -- currently includes the following chapters, all devoted to proxy objects, loading, and syncing:

[image: Book "core concepts" chapter outline]

Comment: The second case does not seem to work. When I try to iterate over `searchKeywordResults.items`, it shows `ItemNotFound` error. It works in the first case though.

Comment: It will be easiest if you can provide a full snippet (with a setup method to populate some data, and then your actual test code -- all ready to click in one go, for debugging).  The best way to do so would be through [Script Lab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab), sharing the snippet as a GIST.  Once we have that, I can take a quick look, and/or pass it along to a Dev on the Word team.

Comment: One other question:  what version number of Word are you using?  Are you on the MSI install of Office 2016, or on a subscription-based install?  (https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/office-versions).

Comment: I changed my code to wrap everything around async and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: excerpt from your book "The part about await-in (or return-ing) a Promise is critical. Just calling context.sync() inside of the body of a function, without awaiting/returning it, will lead to anything from errors being silently swallowed, to everything going completely awry." 

One of the context.sync somewhere wasn't `await`ed. Cleaned up and restructured the code before the snippet, as the snippet on its own was working in the Script Lab.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)